# How to setup BuildBlockerProperty on Jenkins MultiBranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I'm trying to prevent the run of branch_A while branch_B is running.
So I succeeded with normal pipeline with BuildBlockerProperty , job_A stay in pending while job_B job is running.
But with multibranch pipeline, it's not working.

Example for BuildBlockerProperty property for branch_A :

```
properties([
  [
    $class         : 'BuildBlockerProperty',
    blockLevel     : 'GLOBAL',
    blockingJobs   : 'branch_B',
    scanQueueFor   : 'ALL',
    useBuildBlocker: true
  ],
])
```

I saw on [jenkins multibranch doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/) that is it possible but I don't find a way to do that. So if someone have the solution pls !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When you write the branch name, you should write also the multibranch job name.
Exemple :

```
properties([
  [
    $class         : 'BuildBlockerProperty',
    blockLevel     : 'GLOBAL',
    blockingJobs   : 'multibranch_job_name/branch_B',
    scanQueueFor   : 'ALL',
    useBuildBlocker: true
  ],
])
```

But I didn't find a way if you want to run the job only if no other jobs are running. If someone have an idea.

Comment: For you want to do that use this regular expression for "blockingJobs" param :
blockingJobs   : 'multibranch_job_name\\/.*',